# No incomming conn. from local network device: from a local PC using an iPhone-Hotspot-Network connecting to Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop with LAMP/vsftpd/ufw

Tags: 22.04, lamp, localhost

I can not connect to my local webserver that runs Ubuntu 22.04, except I use win7/XAMPP instead.

The Setup is quite simple: I have 2 local PCs, one using win10 and one using ubuntu 22.04 desktop. Both can use the internet, everything works / I can use forefox, I can install via apt... So i set up the LAMP and installed vsftpd to connect via ftp with filezilla (and also http) to the server. But I never get any response. I tried cmd with ping 172.20.10.4 (server) and it says the host does not respond. ftp and http also do not work. Althou the testsite in the server is visible.. apache runs, mariadb/php8.1 are also running.

I used to install and configure the LAMP/vsftpd/ufw using popular and well documented tutorials, using own usernames and so on and so forth - did it carefully. I just dont get it. The same PC used with win7 and XAMPP works fine and is accessible with his ip 172.20.10.4.. (but XAMPP is very slow with large sites)

Can anyone guess what I am missing?

Comment: I use an iPhone 6. The hotspot works like a charm for several different devices in my network like: ipad, pcs, macbook air, adroids and even an iphone 11. Your suggestion to use a network calbe between both pcs is a good point and I would have testet this if I had to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Reason was: the iPhone must have been silently confused about the current devices and ids/ips due to my multiple changes throu reinstalling ubuntu. Althou I did not switch to the xampp version inbetween, it just connected all devices to the internet but NOT between each other anymore. so the solution came up, when I switched back to the xampp server and didnt get any connection to it either. so the network must have been the issue. I restartet both PCs and the iPhone, startet the hotspot and connected them. Xampp was accessible again like before/allways, then i switched to ubuntu system and restartet the iphone and hotspot and the local connection instantly worked.

Cheers and happy happy joy joy ;)